# Sphinx: error on an app that uses flask-login

Tags: flask, python-sphinx, attributeerror, flask-login

When running Sphinx to generate documentation on an app that uses flask-login, I get the error

```
~/workspace/doc/source$ make html
...

File "/Users/prschmid/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 310, in __repr__
obj = self._get_current_object()
File "/Users/prschmid/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 295, in _get_current_object
return self.__local()
File "/Users/prschmid/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 403, in <lambda>
current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _request_ctx_stack.top.user)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'
```

How to create docs for this project?

Comment: Sphinx when create documenation tried to import project and each module in it. I think you'd better post bug report to flask-login developers.

Answer (score 2):

This problem solved in release: Flask-Social==1.6.1 Flask-Login==0.2.6